# Javascript replacing last number digits with 0 instead of representing the number in exponential notation

Tags: javascript, math, exponential

I have javascript code that's supposed to work with big numbers and expect them to be displayed in exponential notation. I can't figure out why x value has the last 4 digits replaced with 0, but y value which is even a bigger number just gets displayed as it's supposed to - with exponential notation. Then I want to display x with fixed points and it returns totally wrong value. The following code was tested in the console. Any idea why this happens?

```
 var y=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111     >     1.1111111111111112e+39  
 var x=111111111111111111111                        >     111111111111111110000
 Number(x).toFixed(4)                               >     "111111111111111114752.0000"
```

```js
var y=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111;
console.log(y);
var x=111111111111111111111 ;
console.log(x);
console.log(Number(x).toFixed(4));
```

Comment: Looks like a rounding error to me

Answer (score 1):

toFixed() returns a string representation of numObj that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If the absolute value of numObj is greater or equal to 1e+21, this method simply calls Number.prototype.toString() and returns a string in exponential notation.

Warning: Floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals precisely in binary. This can lead to unexpected results, such as 0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3 returning false .

For more information check : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 1):

I think the number does not store data to so many digits; in both cases it is same it storing 17 digits and rest is displayed as exponent part;

```
1.111111111111111 2e+39  
11111111111111111 0000
|----------------| 17 digits
```

But turns out somehow the js engine decided to print x without exponent part and the 0 is due to the way big numbers are internally stored; System can only store so many digits after decimal

You can use this

```
Number.isSafeInteger(x) //returns boolean to check if it is safe to use it
```

you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER